# Compile decreases the number of returned list elements

Tags: syntax, compile

I have:

```
LogisticMap = 
  Compile[{μ}, ({μ, #} &) /@ 
    Union[Drop[NestList[μ # (1 - #) &, .2, 300], 100]]];
```

Then:

```
μ = 0.001;
Length[LogisticMap[μ]]
Length[({μ, #} &) /@ 
  Union[Drop[NestList[μ # (1 - #) &, .2, 300], 100]]]
```

produces:

```
9
201
```

So the only difference is in `Compile`. Why does one produce only 9 results while the other 201 (which is correct)?

Comment: Compiled functions use machine precision arithmetic. If you look at the values of the uncompiled function output, they are well below the machine precision threshold (`$MinMachineNumber` = `2.22507*10^-308`): `1.599743743825749*10^-901, 1.599743743825749*10^-898, 1.599743743825749*10^-895, ...`, so the results from compiled and uncompiled code will differ.

Comment: @shrx Yes, but I would expect them to be just zero not to trim the list. That is a bit unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

First off, the compiled function is using machine-precision arithmetic. If you add `RuntimeOptions -> "Quality"` to your compiled function, as per the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html), this specifically catches any underflow with small numbers, and you get the appropriate warning about the underflow.

With regards to your comment:

> Yes, but I would expect them to be just zero not to trim the list. That is a bit unexpected.

Your code trims the list because you use `Union[]` on a list that contains lots of underflowed zeros - of course it will be shorter, look up the definition of [`Union[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html). If you take it out of the compiled code then all is well - the lengths of the arrays are correct, even if the accuracy of the result isn't correct.